# why this regex is not capture before space?

Tags: python, regex

```
text = """group1{
    element : 1
    element : 2
}
"""
for space, char in re.findall(r'^((?:\s{4})*)([^\s]+)', text, re.MULTILINE):
    print(space, char)
```

this code get this result

```
 group1{
     element
     element
 }
```

I want to get result

```
 group1{
     element : 1
     element : 2
 }
```

please help me .. why is not capture this regex before space ?

Comment: You are only capturing `([^\s]+)` which will match first 1+ non-whitespace substring in each line hence only `element` is captured

Comment: how can I capture all of the line using regex? i tried many times but I cannot solve..

Comment: sorry but it get error ..

Comment: i solve! thank you. the answer is '^[\s*].*' .

Comment: Check [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/vTGDxO/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your second group pattern, `([^\s]+)`, that is equal to `(\S+)`, matches any one or more non-whitespace chars. You need to replace it with `(\S.*)` to capture a non-whitespace char that is followed with any zero or more chars other than line break chars.

Also, `\s` matches line breaks, and to get the proper indentation, you need to exclude `\n` at least from `\s`, so you need to replace `\s{4}` with `[^\S\n]{4}`.

You need to use

```py
^((?:[^\S\n]{4})*)(\S.*)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TICqs4/1) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/gCL9OP).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `((?:[^\S\n]{4})*)` - Group 1: any zero or more occurrences of four whitespace chars excluding a newline (line feed) char
- `(\S.*)`  - Group 2: a non-whitespace and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.